# PHP cannot find tables even after successfully connecting to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

The below code re-creates the issue I can't get around. I just can't seem to figure out where the problem lies - in the code? MySQL settings? or somewhere else? Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php 
$db_name = "UserDB";
$open = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if($open)
    echo "1. Successfully connected to MySQL";
echo "</br>";
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $open);
if($db)
    echo "2. Successfully selected {$db_name} database";
echo "</br>";
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM `{$db_name}`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$print = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($result)
    echo "3. {$print} tables found in {$db_name}";
?> 
</body>
</html>

Here's my output:
1. Successfully connected to MySQL
2. Successfully selected UserDB database
3. 0 tables found in UserDB
```

The problem lies in line 3 of the output. It says "0" tables, which is incorrect. I have created "3" InnoDB tables in the selected DB. If I copy/paste and run the same SHOW TABLES query in phpmyadmin, it runs perfectly.

Any idea what is going on here??

Comment: I just ran your code on my localhost, and it seems to be ok. It returns:
1. Successfully connected to MySQL
2. Successfully selected db_name database
3. 8 tables found in db_name.
The problem must be something else not your code.

Comment: What is the value of $result?

Comment: It prints for him "3. 0 tables found in UserDB", so it can't be false because it gets into the if statement.

Comment: @Manolis hmm, so it worked for you. What could be the reason for PHP to not find tables even after establishing a successful connection? This is seriously driving me crazy! :)

Comment: Are you using the same user for both phpmyadmin and for the connection from the website?

Comment: @andrewsi Yes, I'm using the same user for both.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the wrapper function [mysql_list_tables](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php). I found it impossible once to use the SHOW TABLES due to some weird permissions definition, though I could use mysql_list_tables.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It was a non printing character caused from copying text from windows to Mac.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).